# Button text color isn't changing

Tags: angularjs, html, css, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to change md-button text color using accent Palette color using Angular material 1.0.9 version. But it is not changing button text color. 
If i'm using latest beta it got fix. But i'm not going to production with this unstable version.

Code:

```
<md-toolbar class="md-primary md-hue-1">
                <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                    <md-button class="md-accent">My Profile</md-button>
                </div>
 </md-toolbar>
```

Below are the plnkr urls:

Angular material 1-0-9  [Plnkr URL](http://plnkr.co/edit/AB9zScM1aWw97WQn9nmo)

Angular material Latest beta [Plnkr URL](http://plnkr.co/edit/1hO0TZDV5pMFrZ5Hl8bN)

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: I saw it is working on plnkr 1-0-9 you shared above, and when inspect the element I also saw color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87)
Is this your expected behaviour ?

Comment: My expected color is in latest beta plnkr. Purple:800 palette

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with V1.0.9 `md-accent` *within* `md-toolbar` does not work for non-raised buttons but only for raised ones. It works for non-raised buttons outside `md-toolbar`.

The fix would be CSS

```
.md-toolbar-accent span {
    color: #6A1B9A;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WZoAa39yRyJ2VZPAbrqh?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I have check and found the md-accent was override by some class from md-toolbar as you can see as below image

[image: Class was override]

So If you still want to use the color, just added new class

```
.md-button.md-accent {
    color: rgb(106,27,154) !important;
}
```